# Starting Neo4j failed: Component was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Tags: java, neo4j

I was taking a tutorial of Neo4J on Pluralsight and I have to use drwho(doctor who) sample database. I am using Neo4j community edition version 3.0.1. But the sample database(drwho) was made by the old version and I had to set the **dbms.allow_format_migration** property to **"true"**. After doing that, When I tried to start the server it poped up this error

```
Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@673b0b17' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
```

When I take a look at the neo4j log which is found at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\Neo4j Community Edition\logs\neo4j.log

This is what I found

```
Error saving DB location
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .dblocation
2016-06-04 09:19:03.259+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Starting...
2016-06-04 09:19:04.292+0000 INFO  [o.n.b.v.r.Sessions] Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2016-06-04 09:19:04.493+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.p.StoreMigrator] Starting upgrade of database
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem that I was able to resolve. Please have a look at
[Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.1 failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37757051/neo4j-community-edition-3-0-1-failed-to-start)
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thaks for your response. So let met get this straight... do you keep using Neo4j Community edition 2.2.9 or did you just used it to populate(or upgrade) the database using 2.2.9 edition and then use 3.0.1 edition.

Comment: I tried it and it works. But all labels name and coloring are gone.

Comment: I keep using  2.2.9 for my purposes.

Answer (score 2):

The above solution did solve my problem, but it happened again for a different reason. Because of an old neo4j service was still running on my machine.
If you are on windows, check out the neo4j service that is running on Local Service and see the source directory for that service. If it does not match with the one you are having a problem with, disable that service and check again.