# Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.1 failed to start

Tags: neo4j

I populated Neo4j database using Gremlin console 3.1.2.
Checked that data is persistent by exiting the above console and then go back to it pointing to my local database location:

```
>graph=Neo4jGraph.open('/MyNeo4jDB/graphdb')
>g = graph.traversal()
>g.V()
==>v[0]
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
==>v[3]
```

Working on Windows 7 Professional. I also checked that directory C:\MyNeo4jDB\graph.db has been created and populated with files.
I would like to see visual representation of my data by using "Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.1" but got the error "Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@3c5e750c was successfully initialized, but failed to start". 
I know that Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.1" is working fine to display another database.
What is the reason that Neo4j Community Edition failed to open my database? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you check your neo4j log files and perhaps post the error logged there ?

Comment: you have to upgrade your database first, set

Comment: Error saving DB location
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: .dblocation
2016-06-13 13:54:26.999+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase] Starting...
2016-06-13 13:54:28.091+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.p.StoreMigrator] Starting upgrade of database
2016-06-13 13:56:30.801+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.s.p.StoreMigrator] Starting upgrade of database
atabaseException in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.neo4j.desktop.model.DesktopModel.verifyGraphDirectory(DesktopModel.java:128) at org.neo4j.desktop.model.DesktopModel.setDatabaseDirectory(DesktopModel.java:86)

Comment: I fixed a problem by installing older version ( Neo4J Community 2.2.9) as
I recognized that I used older version of neo4j libraries( 2.2.2) to populate database and it has a problem with "Neo4j Community Edition 3.0.1". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to upgrade your database.

Set in neo4j.conf (you can reach it via the "Options" pane in the starter)

```
dbms.allow_format_migration=true
```